# Standard format for webpage builder component templates

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, standards

I want to build a webpage builder with React, where some predfined components can be embedded by the user like e.g. a 'row', 'column' or special predefined widgets. All the components shall be configurable by the user through some variables.
The webpage shall be stored in the database in a certain format, so that the page can be created by parsing the stored format from the database. I haven't found a standard format for that, searching the internet.

But is there some (JSON-)format I could use for my case or should I just invent a JSON-format to store the tree data for the components like so e.g.?:

```
[
  {
    "@component":"row",
    "class": "row",
    "@children":[
      {
        "@component":"column",
        "class": "col",
        "size":3,
        "@children":[]
      } 
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: you mean something like this? https://github.com/formly-js/react-formly

Comment: https://github.com/skidding/react-component-tree